# Как изменить тип textbox с string на integer?

Tags: c#

Как изменить тип `textbox` с `string` на `integer`?

Comment: Вы наверное имеете в виду как получить значение integer из строкового значения текстбокса?

Comment: @Hmayak, Вы имеете ввиду запретить в TextBox'е всё, кроме цифр?

Comment: Я это уже запретил, и в TextBox'е только можно цифры вводит, и все равно эти значение нужно конвертировать, чтобы с ними работать. Вот подумал, может как нибудь сам тип TextBox_а можно изменен с string на integer. Оказалось не можно.

Answer (score 2):

Ну можно попробовать так. Проверки только свои сюда прикрутить придется самому:

```
public class IntBox : Textbox
{
    public new int Text
{
get
{
    return int.Parse(base.Text);
}
set
{
    base.Text = value.ToString();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Но по мне, лучше всё же не переопределить Text а добавить свойство Number. А то логическая не стыковка - Текст и только числа.

Comment: Ну просили изменить тип, а не ввести новое свойство =) А так да, согласен, лучше вводить новое свойство, а не скрывать старое.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, но наверное

```
int i = int.Parse(textBox.Text);
```

Comment: нет, это знаю, не можно поставить по умолчанию тип самого textbox_а  integer?  но чтобы каждый раз не конвертировать

Comment: боюсь это невозможно

Comment: @Spectre, не вводи в заблуждение, будь смелее!

Comment: >поставить по умолчанию тип самого textbox_а integer 

каким бы смелым я не был, это невозможно

Comment: @Spectre - а разве это не возможно:

    namespace MyTextBox
    {
        public class TextBox: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        {
            //а тут как предложил @pincher1519
        }
    }

Comment: создать новый контрол и изменить старый - разве это одно и тоже?

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё оформить расширение не через наследника, а в создании хелпера:

```
public static class TextBoxHelper
{
    public static int GetNumberValue(this TextBox textBox)
    {
        return int.Parse(textBox.Text);
    }

    public static void SetNumberValue(this TextBox textBox, int value)
    {
        textBox.text = value.ToString();
    }

}
```

Подключаете класс, и тогда использовать можете в коде так:

```
var intValue = textBox1.GetNumberValue();
textBox1.SetNumberValue(intValue+1);
```

Забыл как такой статик по науке называется, если кто напомнит, скажу спасибо.

Comment: `Extension method`, и по-моему самое адекватное решение в данном случае

Answer (score 0):

Используй MaskedTextBox.